# Select each file whose name matches one of multiple patterns and is newer than another file

Tags: linux, shell, find

Is it possible to use find to show multiple file names matching different name formats that are newer than a date without having to explicitly use the `-newer` flag for every instance of `-name`? I'm attempting to transition a find command nested inside an rsync from an older script from a file blacklist to a whitelist (a lot more file names are set to be added to the same directory soon that will need to be ignored).

I'm using a lockfile that gets updated as part of a script to find specific files with an mtime newer than its mtime:

```
$ls -la last_script_run.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 user users 29 Aug 10 00:00 last_script_run.lock
```

If I attempt to grab multiple file names I can't get it to work without using the -newer flag for every instance of -name.

**For instance this works:**

```
find $ORIGIN -type f -name "realm_app*" -newer test/last_script_run.lock \
-or -name "realm_sys*" -newer test/last_script_run.lock

test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_10.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_11.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_12.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_13.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_14.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_15.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_16.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_17.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_system_logs_2020_08_16.tgz.closed
```

**This does not:**

```
find $ORIGIN -type f -name "realm_system*" -newer test/last_script_run.lock \
-or -name "realm_app*"

test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_01.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_02.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_03.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_04.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_05.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_06.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_07.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_08.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_09.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_10.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_11.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_12.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_13.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_14.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_15.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_16.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_app_logs_2020_08_17.tgz.closed
test/logfiles/realm_system_logs_2020_08_16.tgz.closed
```

Though the two examples I provided could be caught using one instance of `"realm_*"` I have several other name formats that could not be caught with a single instance of `-name`. For brevity and readability I'd prefer to use the -type f and -newer $lockfile parts of this just once. I got this to work previously using a blacklist of files:

```
find $ORIGIN -newer test/last_script_run.lock -type f -not -name \"*csv*\" \
-a -not -name \"*data-collection*\"
```

I just can't seem to get it to work now that I'm trying to transition this to a whitelist. Is this doable in any way or will I need to add the `-newer` flag to each instance of `-name` in the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parentheses around OR'ed **-name** primaries; this way if any of them evaluates to true and the file being processed is newer than **test/last_script_run.lock**, its name will be printed.

```
find "$ORIGIN" -type f '(' \
    -name 'realm_app*' -o  \
    -name 'realm_sys*'     \
')' -newer test/last_script_run.lock
```

Answer (score -1):

You might consider using `find` to enforce the `-newer` criterion, and then pipe your results to `grep -f`.  Ultimately, `grep -f` may prove to be a more maintainable approach to specifying multiple file names - plus you get the benefit of regular expressions:

```
$ cat file_regexs
^realm_app
^realm_sys

find "$ORIGIN" -type f -newer test/last_script_run.lock | grep -f file_regexs
```

Perhaps your use of `rsync` may make this approach difficult to use, but it may work for other visitors who are looking to find files by names and date.